# Unusual usage of the adverb "yet"

Tags: adverbs

> ...he could have dwelt for a long time ***yet*** in that soft, well-upholstered hell, if this had not happened, this moment of complete hopelessness and despair and the tense moment when he had bent over the flowing water, ready to commit suicide.
>   — [source](http://vietmessenger.com/books/?action=print&title=siddhartha&page=8)

I am wondering what the adverb yet could meant, or would you learn me the construction of such a usage of yet in grammar?

Comment: Using ***yet*** there is a dated/literary alternative to what would normally be expressed as *"he could **still** have dwelt for a long time in that soft, well-upholstered hell"*. But it's translated from [Hermann Hesse *Siddhartha*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22this+soft+well-upholstered+hell%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - and as that link shows, there are many alternative renditions. Personally, I don't think analysing the minutiae of *translations* is a very good way of getting to grips with English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that _"yet" means "still", and it's a bad example for English learners_ would make a fine answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ***yet*** there is a dated/literary alternative to what would normally be expressed as *"he could **still** have dwelt for a long time in that soft, well-upholstered hell"*.

As @200_success comments, *it's a bad example for English learners*. That could ***still*** be contested, of course, but I think this chart shows which way the linguistic wind is blowing...

[image]

---

That's not to imply ***yet*** should be avoided in general. Where it means *[from some time in the past] up until now*, it's perfectly normal *("I haven't finished writing this answer **yet**")*. It's just not such a good choice these days where it references *[some time in the future] after now*, such as *"I could **yet** finish soon"*. <sup>1</sup>

It's also perfectly standard to use ***yet*** as a [conjunction similar to ***but***](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv134.shtml), but even that usage has at least faint overtones of "dated/literary/formal" to some.

---

<sup>1</sup> Noting archaic/literary usages such as *"I met him many years ago, [when he was yet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when%20he%20was%20yet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20he%20was%20yet%3B%2Cc0) a young man"*, that should perhaps be *"narrative reference time"*, rather than *"now".*

Comment: So, would be these a better choice? such as "I could still finish soon". 
I met him many years ago, when he was still a young man",

Comment: @nima: Many competent native speakers (and more particularly, *writers*) still use ***yet*** to reference a future time, so for *them* it's not really appropriate to say ***still*** is "better". But for learners I think it's probably easier (and "safer") to avoid ***yet*** in any context where either ***still*** or ***but*** would also be valid.

Comment: I have to follow my question into another thread. I am looking forward for your invaluable explanations. Thanks inadvance